# Force close when starting service

Tags: android, eclipse, service, android-service

I have an activity and I want it to be updated from a service. when I try to start the service I get a force close error.

**LOGCAT**

```
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service www.freshapp.com.wherewhen.html.SetTime: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2005)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:124)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1022)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at www.freshapp.com.wherewhen.html.SetTime.<init>(SetTime.java:21)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
12-13 15:26:24.574: E/AndroidRuntime(13741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2002)
```

**SERVICE CLASS**

```
public class SetTime extends Service {


private Handler hanl;
private Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View name = inflater.inflate(R.id.editName, null);

View lon = inflater.inflate(R.id.editName, null);

View lat = inflater.inflate(R.id.editName, null);

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){

}

 @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     final LocationManager mlocManager = 
                (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final LocationListener mlocListener = new LocationHelper();
      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
            mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    mlocListener);

            ((TextView) lat).setText(""+ LocationHelper.getLatitude());
            ((TextView) lon).setText("" + LocationHelper.getLongitude());


             hanl.postDelayed(this, 1000);


             //String date = s.format(new Date());
                String mName = ((EditText) name).getText().toString();
                 String mLat = ((EditText) lat).getText().toString();
                 String mLon = ((EditText) lon).getText().toString();




        }
            };
            hanl.postDelayed(r, 1000);


      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }
```

}

**LINE 21**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a `LayoutInflater` in a static initializer. This will not work. Tactically, it will not work because you are trying to call `getSystemService()` on `context`, which is `null` at this point in time.

Moreover, a `Service` has no use for a `LayoutInflater`, so you should delete line 21 and everything that references it, such as all the `EditText` widgets that you cannot use. Or, convert this `Service` into an `Activity`, as an `Activity` has a UI, while a `Service` does not.

Comment: @CommansWare, Well that sucks. Is there a way that I can update that information with a service

Comment: @Christian: Update what information with a service? Or, more to the point, why do you think you need a service in the first place?

Comment: @CommansWare, I need a service so that I can update my database even when the program is closed. But I also want to update the info on the main screen so when the user opens the app he can view what is going on.

Comment: @Christian: "I need a service so that I can update my database even when the program is closed" -- why would the user want to have battery life measuring on the order of a few short hours, running your service continuously in the background, while you keep the GPS and CPU powered on? "But I also want to update the info on the main screen so when the user opens the app he can view what is going on" -- then have your service tell your activity about updated information (broadcast `Intent`, `ContentProvider` and `ContentObserver`, etc.).

Comment: @CommansWare, Hmm, Well I guess I got to rethink this then. I don't wanna run down the batter. thanks for our help.